# What is the purpose/benefit of using the hostsupdater plugin for Vagrant?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

So I'm new to using Vagrant, Homestead, and Laravel. I was introduced to it last week at a new job and now feel comfortable enough to use it at home. At work, the hostsupdater plugin is used, and to be honest I'm not sure exactly what it does. As I go about installing Homestead and Laravel on my home machine (Windows 8.1), I would like to know why this plugin is so beneficial that it is used almost everywhere. I guess in an explain like I'm five way, since I am also new to web development. Is it just allowing me to connect to the web server on the vm through my host machine's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may not belong on SO, and may be better suited for SuperUser or something, however I'll answer anyway.

The hostupdate plugin lets you type a "friendly" url into the browser on your local machine, instead of an IP address.

Usually when you boot a vagrant box, you will need to specify an IP address which it can be accessed at (something like `192.168.50.50` for example). While this is still true even with `vagrant-hostupdater` installed, the plugin modifies your host's (your physical computer) local DNS file (known as a `hosts` file) to tell your computer that the IP address for the vagrant box can also be reached by typing in a more conventional domain name (such as `mybox.dev` or `vagrant-homestead-laravel.local` or whatever is desired).

So the only benefit is instead of having to type into your browser:

```
http://192.168.50.50
```

You can type in some custom string instead, which is probably more memorable:

```
http://mybox.local
```

That's all it does.

On modern windows, this file is located at

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And will have entries in a format similar to the following (one per line):

```
#<ip> <hostname>
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

You can also specify multiple hostnames per IP by separating them with spaces.

```
127.0.0.1    locahost me.local loopback whatever-you-want.anything
```